# How to get Branches List from page model to view on drop down list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I worked on asp.net mvc razor pages . I face issue I can't pass data from page model to view

what i try

1- I create view model as

```
public class AddUserViewModel
    {
       
        public int SelectedBranchId { get; set; }
        public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    }
```

2-Branch Model

```
public class Branch
    {
        [Key]
        public string iBranchCode { get; set; }
        public string vBranchDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

3 - on razor pages `AddUser.cshtml.cs` I get 81 rows on `userModel.Branches`

```
public class AddUserModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public AddUserViewModel userModel { get; set; }
        private readonly ADCContext _db;
        public AddUserModel(ADCContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            userModel = new AddUserViewModel();
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            userModel.Branches= _db.Branch.ToList();// from debug get 81 rows
           //userModel.Branches have 81 rows
        }
       }
```

4 - **on view AddUser.cshtml (main issue )**

How to access `userModel.Branches` Branch List from page model to view

meaning How to fill (81 rows) on drop down list on view from data I received on page model

```
@page "/AddUser"
@model UC.ADC.Host.Pages.Users.AddUserModel
```

my issue on view step number 4 How to get values from `userModel.Branches` on view on drop down list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My issue on view step number 4 How to get values from
> userModel.Branches on view on drop down list

Based on your shared code snippet, you all need to extract your `_db.Branch.ToList()` into a [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and finally in [asp-items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-select-tag-helper)  Select Tag Helper bind the value.

Let's have a look in practice:

**AddUser.cshtml.cs:**

```
public void OnGet()
        {
            userModel.Branches = _db.Branches.ToList();
            ViewData["Branches"] = new SelectList(_db.Branches.ToList(), "iBranchCode", "vBranchDesc");                                      
        }
```

**AddUser.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.AddUserModel
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.userModel.Branches" class="control-label"></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="iBranchCode" asp-items="ViewBag.Branches"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.userModel.Branches" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

**Note:** Only, `<select class="form-control" name="iBranchCode" asp-items="ViewBag.Branches"></select>` would also work.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-select-tag-helper) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-select-tag-helper)

Comment: Glad to know it resolved and happy to assist.